# Equation of an ellipse passing through three points?

Tags: javascript, html, geometry, trigonometry

I would like to create an animation of an object using an elliptical path. I realize there may be an infinite number of possible ellipses given three points, but so long as I can find one that will allow me to animate along that path, I'm fine.

If it helps, the points are (0,0) (500,0) and (1000,1000). So the second point is halfway between the other two.

Comment: There are, as you suggest, infinitely many ellipses that pass through those points, since ellipses have five degrees of freedom (x- and y-coordinates of each focus, and sum of the distances from a given point to each focus). Do you have *any* preference for what ellipse to use? If not, I'd recommend the circle; there's only one circle through those three points, and it's the simplest kind of ellipse to calculate. :-)

Comment: Select a point on a line between the center point and 0,0. Now reflect across the center point to get its counter-focus point. Add the distances between points 1 and 2 to 0,0 to get the constant for those two 'sides' (they of course overlap when connecting to the two outer intersection points). The rest is triangle math.

Comment: @ErikReppen, I don't know the center point.

Comment: Oh sorry, I was thinking of 500,500 based on the "halfway between the two."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ruakh is correct, a circle is the most simple, straightforward approach to this. Here are some equations that can help you:

http://paulbourke.net/geometry/circlesphere/

Comment: Geometry always confuses the hell out of me. Thanks, for this, I'll take a look

Comment: The link generates a 404. Here is the updated one:
http://paulbourke.net/geometry/circlesphere/